# AndroidX Dagger2 MultiDexApplication: Does not implement HasActivityInjector

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-multidex, androidx

I can't find the solution for this problem.

I already have my multi-dex application working, but since I added Dagger 2.16, it's not working..

Here my app class:

```
class App : MultiDexApplication(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }
        AppInjector.init(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = dispatchingAndroidInjector
}
```

**Error at launch**

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your manifest (`AndroidManifest.xml`) and make sure your `<application>` tag lists your App rather than MultiDexApplication, especially if you're not seeing Timber logs before your call to AppInjector.

---

Note that your error message states:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: **androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication** does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector

...which suggests that the class returned by `getApplication()` is of type `MultiDexApplication`, not `App`. In general, Android suggests keeping Application subclasses light; the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#nm) suggest that subclasses are optional, and both DaggerApplication and MultiDexApplication are designed to function in place of a custom Application subclass if you don't otherwise need one. This makes it likely that your manifest wouldn't point to your App class.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the error when I forgot to register the `App` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. I also had to register `MultiDex` in the `attachBaseContext` like so:

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> =
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this)

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }
}
```